# Text View does not automatically scroll

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview

I am printing debug text to my applications text view with

```
- (void) updateDebugWindow:(NSString *)text {
[dbgText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@\r\n",dbgText.text,text]];
}
```

As you can see, the next line will append to the previous so that I can see what happened in the previous step. This works fine

```
[self updateDebugWindow:@"Debug info"];
```

but when it reaches bottom it does not automatically scroll down to show the next line of text, I have to manually scroll it with my finger.

Is there some option in xcode which let the text view automatically follow the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your routine re-written:

```
- (void) updateDebugWindow:(NSString *)text {  
    [dbgText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@\r\n",dbgText.text,text]];  
    [dbgText scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([dbgText .text length], 0)];
}
```

This adds your text, then scrolls to the last "character" in the overall string.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen - Not a problem whatsoever :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSRange selectedRange = dbgText.selectedRange;
[self updateDebugWindow:@"Debug info"];
dbgText.selectedRange = selectedRange;
dbgText.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Hope it will work.